# Unconventional use of Tensorflow Inception model

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

Normally Tensorflow's inception model is used with actual image data containing actual images however, I plan to use it in an unconventional way and was wondering, 1) is this even possible 2) Are the results likely to be so poor that it would be better to find a different way of doing it.

I essentially have a set of textual data that I have converted into a numerical format such as:

`[-0.123123, 0.164564, ...]`.

The conversion was such that similar textual data will have a similar numerical representation in their respective forms. The actual number represent the word vectors for each word within the processed document. This data was then saved as a .jpg file. I plan to create two data classes, 'Similar' and 'non-similar' where similar contains the concatenation of two documents that have been pre-determined to be similar and non-similar contains the concatenation of two documents that have been pre-determined to be non-similar.

The hope been that when this model has been trained upon this data I can feed in an image data which is the combination of two documents numerical matrix form as shown above although not an actual image in the conventional sense of the word, and the model will be able to output with some accuracy either 'Similar' or 'Non-similar' dependant on the two files that made up the base image that was fed into the network. Will Tensorflow's inception even accept such an input?

Comment: I bet even the simplest neural network will do better than the pre-trained inception model for textual data. Inception is a visual model which is trained to extract edges, shapes and patterns in image to do classification. Yours is actually a 1-d signal, but converting to 2-d will make the representation worse as the rows will be highly uncorrelated. Converting your text to word vectors and training an LSTM would be  a better approach that this in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inception network is trained to recognize broad patterns and categorize photos with remarkable accuracy, much like the human eye. If you can tell a difference or similarity between the documents with your eyes, there's a good chance Inception will do the same :)

Although inception's convolutional layers are trained to the [ImageNet task](http://www.image-net.org/), much of the magic happens in the final, fully connected layers, where this data is fed through a softmax classifier, which then spits out the categories and probabilities.

There's a thing called [transfer learning](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining) that retrains these final layers to the categories of your choice. This avoids having to retrain the 30+ convolutional layers (very time consuming), while harnessing the pattern-recognition power of the inception network. Give this a shot, see what it comes up with!

Comment: I am familiar with the concept of Transfer learning and the retraining of the final layers and it is what I intend to do. Hopefully with good results. As there is a significant time cost involved with generating this data for the retraining I just wanted another persons opinion. To your knowledge is there anything that would stop inception been training on incorrectly formatted Jpeg's such as the ones I will provide to it?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the tensorflow jpeg reader, but I guess that it needs a valid header/structure to be able to parse the rows and columns of the image. Why use jpeg, though? Inception can probably convert a csv file to a tensor just fine.